# MDF file security, lock and unauthorized access

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I used SQL Server 2008 R2 database in my application, now I want to install the application for my friend. How can I block access to my database tables and stored procedures ?

I removed Windows authentication and SQL Server Management Studio just login with my own user or pass ! But what happen if he opens my database file in other Management Studio in other systems?

Comment: He can access whatever you've allowed him using the user and password you've given him. If you are sharing a server is one issue. If you are installing a copy of the server, they aren't your tables and stored procedures, they are his. It's his machine...

Answer (score 2):

Your users should *not* have access (ACL permissions) to MDF files, ever. Not at all. They should, instead, have database access, and their account should be set to do what you want them to do, and not to do what you don't.

This is a pretty basic question, really; what you need to look into is SQL Server security, so you can figure out how and what to secure your database with users. But you also need proper file security, as I noted above.

Finally... your question makes me wonder; you do know that SQL Server is not necessarily meant to be installed on every single *client* system, right? You certainly can do that, but it's a *server* product. If you are installing it on a computer to which the user has admin  rights, the game is pretty much over, really.

Comment: +1 - couldn't have said it better. SQL Server isn't just an "Access-on-stereoids" system - it's an entirely different beast (server-based - not file-based)